# correct validate and sql query

Tags: plugins, query, sql

Is this method of operation on the database is safe and correct?

```
 if(isset($_POST['name'])){

    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'_my_table';

    $post = trim(sanitize_user($_POST['name'], true));

    $part = $this->wpdb->prepare("WHERE name = %s", $post)

    $results = $this->wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$table} $part", ARRAY_A)

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is safe.

However, some notes:

1. See the `WP_User_Query` class [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query). This is the, "official," way to do something like this, although you'll get an integer-indexed array of `WP_User` objects. Instead of the `ARRAY_A` that you've specified.
2. You probably don't want `_my_table`, unless your table is called something like `wp__my_table` (note the double underscore after `wp`). The prefix returned from `$wpdb->prefix` includes the underscore that many installations use after the prefix.
3. The `trim()` call after `sanitize_user()` is superfluous. It doesn't hurt anything but it's also a waste of compute cycles.
4. You may be able to write this in one line: `$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("select * from {$wpdb->prefix}my_table where name = %s", sanitize_user($_POST['name'])), ARRAY_A);` This may be better or worse for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I add acceptance to answer sent in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It's close. There's a few things that stand out.

First, I assume you're doing this before the code you shared. It's important to verify a nonce before accepting user input. Read more about [Nonce in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

Next, you want to use `sanitize_text_field` in combination with `wp_unslash`. Trim is more of a helper function than for sanitizing, but it's helpful here to ensure expected results.

Finally, combine your entire SQL query in `$wpdb->prepare()`. Remember `$wpdb->prefix` usually includes an underscore. Your code would produce `wp__my_table`, for example (2 underscores).

**Note:** I changed `$this->wpdb` to the global `$wpdb`. This is probably unnecessary for you, but I wanted to make sure others that landed on this answer had the right context. I also changed the table name to posts and the name to title for testing.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['name'] ) ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_name = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( trim( $_POST['name'] ) ) ) );

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_title = %s", $post_name );

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
}
```

For more information on WordPress coding standards for sanitizing input data, check out [The WordPress Coding Standards](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/wiki/Fixing-errors-for-input-data).